# EF Core, use include or again context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, include, dbcontext

Since:

> "Eager loading a collection navigation in a single query may cause
> performance issues."

see: [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)

And it is advise to use split queries with include. I wonder if instead of include in the query bellow:

```
            var task = await context.Tasks                   
                .Include(x => x.TaskDependencies)                 
                .Select(x => new TaskBaseModel
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Name = x.Name,
                    Description = x.Description,                        
                    TaskDependencies= x.TaskDependencies.ToArray()
                })
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == _id);
```

I should do this:

```
                var task = await context.Tasks                                                       
                    .Select(x => new TaskBaseModel
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        Name = x.Name,
                        Description = x.Description,                        
                        TaskDependencies= context.TaskDependencies
                           .Where(y => y.TaskId == x.Id).ToArray()
                    })
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == _id);
```

Anyone as any info regarding this? about performance, etc..

Regards

Comment: The documentation refers to `Include` method. The `Include` calls in both your queries are one and the same (`.Include(x => x.TaskDependencies)`), so what is the question actually?

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove the second include, updated it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both queries should have the same performance and SQL. Note that `Include` followed by `Select` is ignored by EF Core.

So, most comfortable query is:

```cs
var task = await context.Tasks                   
    .Select(x => new TaskBaseModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Description = x.Description,                        
        TaskDependencies = x.TaskDependencies.ToArray()
    })
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == _id);
```

Comment: Include is ignored followed by select since when? And the query you posted wont work because TaskDependencies is a Collection..

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes I have tried

Comment: Which exception do you have?

Comment: You mean If I had tried without the include? I thought you meant with the include and the select at the same time.. No exception without the include, but I wonder why it works if its a navigation property? is it because of the select??

Comment: It is how LINQ translator works, if it see in lambda body reference to navigation property it makes assumptions how to rewrite query. Actually after rewriting it will create your second sample. It simple explanation, behind the scenes a tons of code which simplifies work with entities via navigation properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237633/discussion-between-marchalpt-and-svyatoslav-danyliv).

Comment: Is selecting then getting one value OK? In situations like this, I always do `SingleOrDefault` first, get the entity in a variable, then create the entity model in a separate statement. If this is fine, I might use this in the future.

Comment: @M.Azyoksul, actually it is bad practice. Your DTO might not require all properties, but you have loaded everything from database.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I see. I always thought it was like this. It gets all entities, maps all entities, then selects a single one. But it is not like that.